# Get maximum available height of PageViewModel in Introduction Screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Import this package `flutter pub add introduction_screen` and replace the code of the flutter demo app with the code below, to reproduce my request.

**What I want:** I want to know the exact spacing between `globalHeader` and `dotsContainer` of IntroductionScreen. And this spacing I want to initialize to the variable pageHeight of PageViewModel's, so that I can set `useScrollView` from PageViewModel to false  without getting a PixelOverflow error.

*In other words:* The purple Container of picture below should not be scrollable and fit the whole available size AND I want to know the value of this size. So please no solutions with Expanded.

My Idea: The introduction Screen has a defined high by its parent Container . (In my case it's  `maxHeight * 2/3`. So from this I  have to subtract the height of `globalHeader` (which has a Text Widget with fontSize 20) and the height of dotsContainer. To try this idea I need the height of the dotsContainer of IntroductionScreen...

Thanks to everybody who can help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: TestIntroductionScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TestIntroductionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestIntroductionScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
            kToolbarHeight +
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom);
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.right -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.left;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('HomePage'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: maxWidth,
            height: maxHeight * 2 / 3,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: IntroductionScreen(
              globalBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
              globalHeader: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child:
                      Text('   Your Pages:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))),
              showDoneButton: false,
              showBackButton: true,
              next: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
              back: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
              pages: [buildTestPage(maxWidth, maxHeight)],
              controlsMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              controlsPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: maxWidth,
            height: maxHeight * 1 / 3,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  PageViewModel buildTestPage(double width, double height) {
    double pageHeight = height * 2 / 3;
    return PageViewModel(
      // useScrollView: false,
      titleWidget: Container(width: width, height: pageHeight, color: Colors.purple),
      body: '',
      decoration: const PageDecoration(
        contentMargin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 0),
        footerPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        imagePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        fullScreen: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][2]

[image]

Comment: seems you are already measuring the height and providing the ration. sorry not getting the issue

Comment: Just run the code and see that the purple field is much larger and scrollable but i want it to look the same without being scrollable

Comment: same height and stop scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current UI, the middle dots will take `125` pixel. you can split into half, and reduce the height from top and bottom part,

```dart
class TestIntroductionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestIntroductionScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('HomePage'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (p0, constraints) {
          final maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
          final maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight;

          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: maxWidth,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: IntroductionScreen(
                    globalBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    globalHeader: const Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text('   Your Pages:',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))),
                    showDoneButton: false,
                    showBackButton: true,
                    next: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
                    back: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
                    pages: [
                      buildTestPage(maxWidth, maxHeight / 2 - (125 / 2)),
                    ],
                    controlsMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    controlsPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: maxHeight / 2 - (125 / 2),
                width: maxWidth,
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  PageViewModel buildTestPage(double width, double height) {
    return PageViewModel(
      useScrollView: false,
      titleWidget: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        height: height,
      ),
      body: '',
      decoration: const PageDecoration(
        contentMargin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 0),
        footerPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        imagePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        fullScreen: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]